# What proportion of the circle is covered by the square?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, circles

Or what is the combined area of the circle segments (chords)?

Picture a circle which is covered by a square, where the bottom vertices of the square are inscribed within the circle (so that the distance between the circle centre and the corners of the square is the radius). The top edge of the square is tangent to the top of the circle, so you have a square which covers all of the circle except for 3 chords (2 of which are equal).

It would probably help to draw it!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried drawing it? I believe that this is an AMC 8 question.

Comment: I have drawn it and I could find the bottom chord area by using a generic formula from wikipedia but the other 2 chord areas are harder to find and I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Near universal rule: Put a dot at the **centre** of the circle. Then draw lines from the centre to the corners of the square, and to the point of tangency.

Comment: I have done that, but only one triangle nicely fits into the circle.

Comment: What area did you get for the bottom chord?

Comment: $\dfrac{r^2 \pi}{4} - \dfrac{r^2}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this, but I am afraid that it is not a simple one.

Referring to the diagram below:-

[image]

The vertical length of the square = the green line = R + R cosθ

The horizontal length of the square = 2 R sinθ

∴ 2 R sinθ = R + R cosθ

If we let 2x = θ, then 2 (2 sin (x) cos (x)) = 2 cos2 (x)

∴ Cos (x) [cos (x) – 2 sin (x)] = 0

Rejecting the solution for cos (x) = 0 and obtain tan (x) = 1/2

Once x (and hence θ) is known, then the rest is found by:-

Area of the segments combined

= area of the circle – area of the square + 2 * area of the yellow shard part

Area of the yellow shaded part

= area of quad OPCQ – area of OQS – area of sector OPS

= R(R sinθ) – (0.5)(R sinθ)(R cosθ) – Rθ